# Localstorage css style change

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

Hello guys I have problem with webstorage API, so basically I have select element and button with "onclick" attribute, I would like to change background color of some div but using localstorage to remeber that settings in different session. Almost everything works fine (bgcolor changes etc) except that it is not remebered in next session. So it seems like localstorage doesnt work at all.
here is my javascritp code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bgcol(){
        document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = localStorage.kolor;
    }
    function zmiana(){
        var tlo = document.getElementById("kolortla").value;
        localStorage.setItem('kolor', tlo);
        document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = localStorage.kolor;
    }

</script>
```

html onload

```
<body onload="bgcol" >
```

and select

```
<select id="kolortla" >
   <option value="gold">złoty</option>
   <option value="yellow">żółty</option>
   <option value="green">zielony</option>
   <option value="red">czerwony</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="zmiana()" value="zmiana"/>
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan'); https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) about how to use LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

you're also fetching `document.getElementById('div')` which doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You are using the localStorage object incorrectly.

To save an item, use:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("color", value);
```

To get an item, use:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("color");
```

In your onload attribute on the body tag, the function must be called with "()"

```
<body onload = "bgcol()"> <!--- HTML --->
```

Also, to change the background color, you are referencing a `<div>` tag that does not exist. You can change the background color of the page with

`document.body.style.background = "green";`

Here is a good read on how to use the LocalStorage API [LocalStorage Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)